# LXD/LXC External Network Accessibility Issue

Tags: lxc, lxd

Anyone experienced something like this? Absolutely strange as f..k

I have multiple containers(ubuntu 16.04) on ubuntu host.
After system reboot, some of the containers are not able to access external network but internal access works fine.

Exactly one hour after, those affected containers start working fine.

I cannot find any evident log in the server(Dell R630) or on the firewall(Cisco ASA 9.X). It looks like there must be some sort of a timer with this issue as it always lasts one hour.

We never had this kind of issue with Solaris with VM.

Is this some kind of lxd bug? Anyone has a clue?

Thanks